# What is the changed file size in plone during version control?

Tags: python, plone

I have a file uploaded to plone say size 1 MB. After checkout and downloading it, I edit and then upload and check-in. What is the size of the new uploaded file in plone site. It is the original size + added size  OR the size of the new uploaded file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the Working-copy-support option: Files are excluded from the possibility to be checked-out. Probably exactly because of the reasons you are rising. Versioning attached files is easily blasting the DB because every file would be kept in the DB and thus (to answer your question) the object's size would be a sum of all of them.

Also the standard-versioning-history is not applied to files.

Comment: you mean to say that when the files are versioned, each version has its own size and no way related to the old file. Any new size added/removed to/from  the original size is not considered. It is independant of versioning Example. A file of 1 MB uploaded, checked-out,edited with new contents added to it, and  uploaded again and checked-in to its original place is not an additional 1 MB, but of size 2 MB, considering the fact that the size of new contents added is 1 MB?

Comment: Not sure, if I understand your question. Are you referring to the working-copy-support or something else?

Comment: Just stumbled over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097843/do-as-many-copies-as-the-number-of-revisions-exist-for-a-file-in-plone, where you ask a similar question and Martijn provides an excellent answer...