# Plone maximum number of revisions a file can have?

Tags: plone

What is the maximum number of revisions that Plone 4.2.1 can offer for any uploaded file?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097843/do-as-many-copies-as-the-number-of-revisions-exist-for-a-file-in-plone

Comment: @Sait not really...please understand the difference!

Comment: I suppose you want a better bound than the 2^128 limit on blobs you can concurrently have in bushy layouts?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz you mean to say that every file can have 2 to the power of 128 times of revisions in Plone?

Comment: No, you cannot have more than 2^128 blobs in total at the same time, across all relevant revisions of all files in your database, including images. (Basically, the filenames that are generated run out at that point.)